# How can I tackle Attribute Error when I import tensorflow_datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter, tensorflow-datasets

I have been trying to import the tensorflow_datasets module but it repeatedly shows an attribute error.

I have tried clearing the cache, reinstalling the package again and also restarting the device multiple times. Nothing seems to work. It shows the following error while importing tensorflow_datasets:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'dtypes'

I have also updated the versions of jupyter notebook, anaconda and the packages. Nothing seems to work. A request extended to anyone who would be able to help with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the full error stack trace (no image please) and also a minimal reproducible code example which triggers the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.